# VGA programming without using interrupt (only registers)

Tags: interrupt, vga

I want to develop a VGA graphics driver (for Linux(Ubuntu)) with support for the basic primitives such as putpixel, drawline, fillrect and bitblt. I want to do it in protected mode. 
I´ve been googling for a week and the following four links are the best I have found:

http://www.brackeen....vga/basics.html
http://www.osdever.n...VGA/vga/vga.htm
http://bos.asmhacker...sing%20bios.htm

Unfortunately, the first one uses a BIOS call so I cannot use it. The second link has lots of information on the VGA registers but no examples showing how to make them work together. The third example is a example to switch in 13h mode but i've tried it and nothing happened. Can you guys give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

--Vincenzo

Answer (score 1):

my code at http://bos.asmhackers.net/docs/vga_without_bios/snippet_5/vga.php
works fine if you are in 32bit mode with full hardware access. Unfortunately I doubt that any Linux variant will let you directly access the VGA ports. I'm not sure how you develop this driver, but if you made sure that you have full access to the VGA ports it should work. In my example code I only switch between mode 0x03 and 0x13, but in the folders above you'll be able to find port values for most other common VGA modes, as well as C code to do the switch if you prefer that.

Comment: This code can't be assembled... it makes references to symbols such as `font_8x16` and `cls` which are nowhere to be found in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Christoffer code include files are found BOS operating system source code like text.inc and font8x16.inc

http://bos.asmhackers.net/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

This is coming many many years later but I think it's still very relevant and if somebody is struggling I hope they can find it useful.

First of all, it is completely possible to configure VGA only using registers without interrupts, as hard as it may be. A useful resource about registers and how to configure them can be found [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware), but unless you have a ton of time to spare to learn how to properly do all of it, move to the following section.

If you wish to really learn how to do it, I suggest going through with the documentation provided earlier. However, some of it is already done!

Chris Giese did a great job demonstrating exactly how to do this for MS-DOS system, and while you may think that doesn't help you, it really does.

Chris's code can be found [here](https://www.singlix.com/trdos/archive/vga/modes.c). If you want another useful codes check [here](https://www.singlix.com/trdos/archive/vga/) as well.

Now, while it only works for MS-DOS it's actually easy to convert to other systems. The code already contains all data needed to configure the registers in many different modes. And that's the part that saves you a ton of time going through documentation.

The code uses functions `outportb`, `inportb`, which are MS-DOS functions, to write/read single byte to/from a port. Therefore, you have to redefine these functions to read/write for your own system. Redefinition complexity depends on the system you operate on.

In addition, you will also need to provide means to write to physical memory region between `0xA0000-0xBFFFF` which corresponds to standard VGA memory area. Once you have that allocated, you need to also redefine the functions `pokeb` `pokew` `peekb` which will help you output things (text or pixel data) on the screen.

One last note: the code is already defined to work with many different modes including both text and display modes.